# Deeplink issue in Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have integrated deeplink in the project as per the android documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

It is working fine for other Android version but in Android 10 it is showing option dialog for app and chrome, I need to open it directly inside the app. This is specific to android 10 only.

```
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="com.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I have also  verified deeplink in assets json file and shows correct SHA-256 key

https://my.domain/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration of your Android, see the first [paragraph on deep links documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking):

```
1. Open the user's preferred app that can handle the URI, if one is designated.
2. Open the only available app that can handle the URI.
3. Allow the user to select an app from a dialog.
```

Whats happening is that your app and chrome as well are able to handle the deep link so Android lets decide the user which app to open it with until the user selects an app for"always open with".

If you want to make sure only your app is ever chosen, you can use a custom scheme like *yourAppName* and use URI like yourAppName://com.example.com